# How to use {% include ''" %} in Shopify for an app

Tags: include, frontend, shopify

I have a shopify test app (written in rails) here: 
http://csiga-second-shopify.herokuapp.com/

How can I make a very easy app, that is includable by a store owner.
I'd like to do it similar to AddThis app.
( http://www.addthis.com/shopify/preferences#.UCPF28ge6CU )

How to connect {% include 'foo' %} function to my deployed app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add an Asset to a Shop when your App is installed, you have to first have the merchant approve your App for adding assets to the shop. Second, you have to install your asset, in this case 'foo.liquid'. Once it is an Asset in the shop, you could have the theme reference the asset, using include.

Note that this is a little tricky since when the merchant uninstalls the App, any assets you installed are not automatically removed. That could be considered litter.

Answer (score 0):

Where you want to add {% include 'foo' %} in your deployed app?? 
And AddThis link does nothing but just redirects to the login page of Shopify. If you want to publish your app first built it then get it tested on the Shopify Test Commpunity present on google groups and then send it for publishing. After 15 days they will reply with the message saying your app has been published.

You cannot add with current APIs what Shopify provides any liquid code into their page. You can add Javascripts which can even act as stylesheets to it.

Comment: No, I don't want to add {% include 'foo' %} to my deployed app. I'd like that if someone (a store owner) add {% include 'foo' %} to his template (and he installed my app before) then a part of my app will be displayed.

Comment: The only issues is you cant add a snippet to the Shopify account of the user using the app. You need to give him instructions on how you should create a snippet and add code what you want in that snippet. Then tell them wherever they want to use your app code add the following {% include 'your_snippet_name' %} to the template. You cant even modify the template of the user as you are only able to modify name or certain things but not the body of the template.